# How to load Bash with .bash_profile from different folder

Tags: bash, bashrc

I have a shell script project where I want to load the .*rc from the project folder.

In zsh I can achieve this by `ZDOTDIR=$PWD zsh` which will load the `.zshrc` from the current folder.

How can I do the same in Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch bash with the --rcfile option

```
bash --rcfile ./project/bashrc
```